# Create Excel chart programmatically in PHP

Tags: php, excel

Do you have any idea on how to create a chart in an Excel sheet programmatically from PHP ?

I know you can invoke the Excel COM object, but the server is running on a Linux machine...

I already use the excellent PHPExcel library but they do not offer the option to create charts.

Thanks !

Comment: Don't they, I thought they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give Google Charts API a go.

Aonther option you could look at is RRD tool, see [here](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/index.en.html)

HTH

Comment: I like the suggestion of using Google Charts, I didn't even think of that right off the bat.

Comment: Good idea ! You can then paste the image of the chart using:

file_put_contents('graph.png', file_get_contents($GOOGLE_CHART_PATH));

Comment: @Baba: thank you for pointing it out, removed the link. Seems the site may have been pulled off.

Comment: Add another link instead .. you question is to plain .. and give some example if you can

Comment: Google Charts Images is now deprecated and will be gone next year.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a bad idea to use PHPs GD library like these

[WS Charts](http://www.w4schools.org/manuals/WS%20Charts-En.htm)

[Bar graph tutorial](http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=20)

or [JpGraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/), I'm not sure of the internals but there is free PHP5 and PHP4 versions available

Answer (score 0):

Google Charts is a nice idea. 
I would use built-in PHP draw functions to generate a chart, though.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that using Excel is the best way of generating a chart. Typically, with ASP.net, you would either write your own chart rendering, or you would use an external component to do this (liberal definition).

My suggestions:

1. Pipe the data into gnuplot, customize it and grab the output
2. Get a third party widget to send the data into and handle the user interaction (Highly recommended)
3. Write your own chartting control (free from licensing issues, but not worth the annoyances unless you really like doing graphics your self)