# Using PHP and SQL to generate Excel files with statistical graphs and piecharts?

Tags: php, jquery, excel, graph, pie-chart

I got a database with a lot of number statistical related info, which i'm looking to generate out in an excel file.

1. So first of all of all, do anyone of you have experience with any popular libraries/scripts to generate excel files?
2. Secondly, im thinking it would be cool to display some of these very dull and boring numbers, in pie charts and graphs. Again, do anyone of you have experience with any popular libraries/scripts to generate such things inside an excel file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try PHPExcel library - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

It satisfied all my needs, including the ones you specified, but not limited to only them.

Might need to increase memory limit a bit though since in large data cases as the one you specified it consumes a significant amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I can second the PHPExcel library, I have used it a couple of times in the past and it works great. Unfortunately you cannot create charts with it as far as I remember. Someone else brought up this question before, maybe you will find something helpful here

[Create Excel chart programmatically in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558425/create-excel-chart-programmatically-in-php)